# rstudio cannot be installed on this environment (Anaconda3 on Windows 10)

Tags: rstudio, anaconda3

I am on Windows 10, and have installed Anaconda3 individual edition (version 2020.11, latest as of Dec. 12, 2020). I want to install RStudio inside Anaconda3.

I created a new environment called renv (also tried rstudio, renv2, etc) and checked both Python (3.8) and r. Then, I tried to install RStudio on this environment. Unfortunately, I always got this error: rstudio cannot be installed on this environment. It asks me whether I'd like to create a new environment (which is exactly what I have done). So, I created a new environment and the same error occurred, over and over again.

Some things I have tried so far:

- Tried installing for all user
- Tried installing only for me
- Tried running the exe installer as a normal user
- Tried running the exe installer as an administrator
- Tried checking "using Anaconda3 as the system Python3"
- Tried unchecking "using Anaconda3 as the system Python3"

No luck in resolving the issue...
I had this problem several months back, hoped new releases will not have the problem. Unfortunately, the error persists.

Can someone help?

Comment: I am using the 64-bit version. I am using Anaconda-Navigator.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps may work.

1. Make a clean installation of *Anaconda* with defaults selected
2. Login with your *Anaconda* account in the *Anaconda Navigator*, and
   leave (exit) it
3. Open *Anaconda Prompt* (as an administrator)
4. Create a new environment (say `myRandPy`) with `R` and `Python` both with
   R essentials and R base and Rstudio package, all in a single command

```
conda create -n myrandpy r python r-essentials r-base rstudio
```

5. Press `y` and hit `Enter` when asked.
6. Go to *Anaconda Navigator* to activate the new environment and launch *Rstudio*

Hopefully, this will solve the issue.